# Global optimization across sites for negative exponential function

Tags: r, optimization, global

Trying to estimate the best parameters that suites for across the study. Each study has different length of datasets and needs to see what are the best parameters for the negative exponential model fitted between Remaining and Time variables. Sample dataset is as follows;

```
Study <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3))
Time <- as.numeric(c(0, 0.08, 0.16, 0.24, 0, 0.05, 0.88, 0, 0.99))
Remaining <- as.numeric(c(100, 80, 69, 45, 100, 60, 35, 0, 25))
data_n <- cbind(Study, Time, Remaining)
head(data_n)
```

Need to optimise negative expoenetial function can calculate K and K2 that suites accross the all the sites. The function is

```
Predicted_remaining <- 41* exp(-k*Time) + (100-41) * exp(-k2*Time)
```

Value 41 is a constant and -k and -k2 are the parameters of the negative exponential function that need to optimise. Trying to optimise in R so any advice is 
greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I create a data frame from your data. Next, I define the function that will be fit to the data, which takes the fitting parameters, `p`, and `time` as arguments. Then, I create a cost function that calculates the sum of the squares as a metric of the fit quality. After that, I use `optim` to minimise the cost function and, finally, plot the results.

```
# Create data frame
data_n <- data.frame(Study, Time, Remaining)

# Function to be fit
fit_function <- function(p, time){
  (41 * exp(-p[1] * time) + 59 * exp(-p[2] * time))
}

# Cost function using the sum of squares
cost_function <- function(p, data){
  sum((data$Remaining - fit_function(p, data$Time))^2)
}

# Using 'optim' to minimise the cost function
fit <- optim(c(1, 1), cost_function, data = data_n)

# Plot results
plot(data_n$Time, data_n$Remaining, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Remaining")
lines(seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), fit_function(fit$par, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lyngbakr. Is it possible to use the same approach and find the best solution across the all the "Study" sites? This is because each "Study' is a sperate study.  It's something like a global optimisation I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "best solution across all study sites". The given answer provides the best fit taking into account all study sites. Or do you want to fit it to data for each study individually? (I'm not sure this is possible given that there are only two observations for site 3.)

Comment: Thanks, Lyngbakr. I think this is a global optimisation can we mixed all the data from all the sites. Is it possible to add a constraint saying -p[1] is having higher negative value over -p[2]. Example -p[1] can be -5 and -p[2] can be -2.

Comment: Check out `?optim`, as it explains how to constrain parameter values.